# Browser crash when trying to convert HTML+ SVG content to scaled image using html2canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, jquery-plugins, html2canvas

I am using [Treant.js](http://fperucic.github.io/treant-js/) javascript library to create an organisational chart.

[image: Treant.js Screenshot]
I used the following code to convert the SVG elements (the lines that connect the boxes) and HTML contents (the boxes):

```
var useWidth = $( '#orgchart' ).prop( 'scrollWidth' ); 
var useHeight = $( '#orgchart' ).prop( 'scrollHeight' ); 

var scaleBy = 5;

var w = useWidth;
var h = useHeight;
var scaledCanvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
scaledCanvas.width = w * scaleBy;
scaledCanvas.height = h * scaleBy;
var scaledContext = scaledCanvas.getContext( '2d' );
scaledContext.scale( scaleBy, scaleBy );

html2canvas( $( "#orgchart" ), {
    canvas : scaledCanvas,
    logging : false,
    onrendered : function ( canvas ) {

        $( "#orgChartSketchDivBody" ).html( "<canvaS id=\"orgChartSketch\"></canvas>" );

        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL( 'image/png' );
        }
} );
```

This works fine as long as the chart is small. But for large charts, when rendered, the browser freezes and crashes (I am using latest Chrome).

I know the scale value 5 is high, but I need high quality images so as to get readable images of large charts.

Is there any solution to stop the browser from crashing?

Comment: I don't get what you are doing... Could you provide an [MCVE] ? If I read it correctly, you are only resizing the raster version of your chart returned by html2canvas. Why ? You won't win any readability doing so.

Comment: @Kaiido Hey Kaiido. Resizing and scaling the canvas does make the image quality alot better. It increases the size of the file as well, but file size isn't a problem in my project.